# Why are Terminators' eyes always red?

Tags: the-terminator-series

Can anyone explain to me why hard-metal endoskeleton Terminator models always have red-colored eyes? Is this for some technical reason?

Comment: It looks really cool.

Comment: Red is menacing and demonic.

Comment: Because they see in infra-red and in the movies that means "glowing red".

Comment: Red LEDs are cheaper to make. Skynet is trying to save a few cents.

Comment: @Jhon Sensebe, Good Point...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### They aren't always red

In the pilot for [Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator:_The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles),  and throughout the first season, the '[Cameron](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cameron)' Terminator demonstrated the ability to make her eyes **glow blue**.

[image]

It's worth noting that at the end of season 2, we see that [her endoskeleton](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/terminator/images/0/08/TOK715head.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20081004024556) has  classic Terminator red eyes. The show's writers [claim that her (hardware) eyes were always red](http://www.savethescc.com/transcribing-the-awesome/) and that the blue glow was the result of some form of software control of the filters used in her eyes.

---

The [T-X](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-X_(character)) in [Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_3:_Rise_of_the_Machines_(film)) has blue eyes.

Interestingly, the choice of eye colour for both models seems to have been motivated (out of universe) to distinguish these anti-terminator-terminators from their classically eye-coloured brethren

[image]

Comment: I would say that, from the evidence, the eye color seems more likely to be split along gender lines.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Although that may be superficially true, the reality is that Cameron is no more female than Arnie is male. As they say in the resistance, it's just a skinjob.

Comment: But out of universe, they're played by men and women, and the eye color seems to correspond to the main actor's gender. You know, I'm thinking that it might have to do more with changing technology in the real world. Red LEDs have been around a lot longer than blue ones, so we associate blue lights with more advanced, "sleeker" technology, and the "female" Terminators are newer designs.

Comment: Do we ever see the lighted eyes of the Ginger Terminator that Cameron fights in the elevator?

Comment: @JackBNimble - No. She has blue eyes, but we never see her endoskeleton eyes; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_ddHsX6EDk

Comment: Cameron's eye color is explained in http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-900_(The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles)#Notes

Comment: @Oriol - Hmm. Smells like a retcon to me. Regardless, I've edited to reflect what they've said.

Comment: @Oriol I don't trust that Terminator wikia. 
"John Connor has been portrayed by more actors than any other character in sci-fi film and television history (7 actors);[2] with the exception of James Bond (7 actors)[3] and the Doctor of Doctor Who (34 actors, though only twelve are official Doctors)."

- In other words, has **not** been the most portrayed...