# Is Star actually a Terminator or hybrid?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-salvation

Star, the mute child companion of Kyle Reese in *Terminator: Salvation.*

From the ending of [Alan Dean Foster](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/11735.Alan_Dean_Foster)’s *Terminator: Salvation* [novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4523220-terminator-salvation):

> Lying on its floor near the back, Connor—badly damaged but still alive. His wife tending to him with a mixture of professionalism and affection. Kyle Reese, tougher than he knew. The little girl Star, silent but aware.
>
> Reaching into the chopper, the moonlight softened and seemed to heal all of them, rendering Kate Connor’s face angelic instead of just determined, making Reese look as young as he actually was, **glinting redly off one of Star’s eyes....**
>
> Wright blinked. The glint was gone. As if it had never been.
>
> It was nothing at all, he told himself with assurance. There had been nothing there, nothing to see. The briefest of flickers of moonlight on cornea. Nothing more than a second of reflection, singular twinkle. Or a singularity.

Is Star actually a terminator or new hybrid sent to infiltrate the Resistance? Was this something that may have been true at the time Foster wrote the novelization, then abandoned, or always something Foster added just to play coy with readers?

### What’s the story with Star’s red-glinting eye?

Comment: Well that's it, isn't it. We just don't know. [The end (or is it?)](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheEndOrIsIt)

Comment: Terminator eyes don't glow red by accident; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133142/why-are-terminators-eyes-always-red

Comment: If she's a hybrid infiltrator, she's doing a terrible job. She has access to Kyle, Kate and John for years. Unless her goal is to *protect* Kyle, which makes no good sense in light of the events of Salvation and Genisys.

Comment: @Valorum and in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133142/why-are-terminators-eyes-always-red you referenced that "the blue glow was the result of some form of software control of the filters used in her eyes", so in this case that could be a software glitch, a hint for something, or just some weird reflection (and so only one red eye)

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - Oh sure, it could be. It isn't, but it could be.

Comment: @Valorum Can the words  “good sense” be used in light of Genisys, though?

Comment: @Valorum - I think the implication isn't that she was ALWAYS one, but that the "Star" found by Kyle in the facility at the end was a duplicate meant to infiltrate. Of course, at that age, she would only have about a year or so before people noticed she wasn't growing up.

Comment: @Omegacron - I felt the implication was that Wright is having some kind of stress-based nervous breakdown where he sees terminators *everywhere*.

Comment: “Bzzzt! HK-Star, if you can’t kill the Resistance in about 6 months time, you need to start smoking a lot of cigarettes to give an appearance of stunting your growth.”

Comment: Is it really a breakdown if they _are_ everywhere?

Comment: @SillybutTrue - "*They called me mad, but I showed them!"*